# Error IMAPClient with message_string() function

Tags: perl

you have an idea on how to solve this problem that I met with the function message_string () of Mail::IMAPClient library, here is my code:

```
     #!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mail::IMAPClient;
use IO::Socket::SSL;



 # Create the object connexion with socket SSL + LOG ON
my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
 #Debug    => 1,
  User     => 'xxxxx',
  Password => 'yyyyy',
  Uid      => 1,
  Peek     => 1,  # set \Seen flag
  Socket   => IO::Socket::SSL->new(
                Proto    => 'tcp',
                PeerAddr => 'zzzzzzz',
                PeerPort => 993,
              )
);
   die "$0: connect: $@" if defined $@;


my $nm=$imap->unseen_count("INBOX") ;
# Select INBOX dossier
$imap->select("INBOX");




      my $msg = $imap->message_string('47') or die " $@\n";
```

the error obtained is the following:

```
message_string() expected 304627 bytes but received 304718 you may need the IgnoreSizeErrors option
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly how to cope with this.  Some IMAP servers calculate the message size incorrectly -- in particular, many (such as notably GMail) examine the local message size, then change the line terminators to CRLF when sending the message over IMAP, resulting in a slightly different actual size than what the server told the client to expect.  By default, IMAPClient will throw an error when this happens, but you can tell it not to by saying `IgnoreSizeErrors => 1` when you create an instance.

```
my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
 #Debug    => 1,
  User     => 'xxxxx',
  Password => 'yyyyy',
  Uid      => 1,
  Peek     => 1,  # set \Seen flag
  Socket   => IO::Socket::SSL->new(
                Proto    => 'tcp',
                PeerAddr => 'zzzzzzz',
                PeerPort => 993,
              ),
  # See here
  IgnoreSizeErrors => 1
);
```

Comment: The documentation says Exchange but my memory says GMail. I could be misremembering; it's been a while.